# Magento 2 : How to change state list for USA?

Tags: magento2, address, state, address-attribute

How can I change/remove some states from Shopping Cart and Checkout page?

For example. I need to remove:

- American Samoa;
- Virgin Islands;
- Armed Forces Africa (Americas, Canada, Europe, Middle East, Pacific);
- etc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has already been asked and resolved here - [How to change state list for USA in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241799/how-to-change-state-list-for-usa-in-magento-2)

Quoting it for your reference;

> You can filter out the options using a Plugin for the
>   `toOptionArray()` method of
>   `Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection`:
>
> ```
> class StateFilter
> {
>     protected $disallowed = [
>         'Guam',
>         'Puerto Rico',
>         'Palau',
>         'Virgin Islands',
>         'Northern Mariana Islands',
>         'Marshall Islands',
>         'Federated States Of Micronesia',
>         'American Samoa',
>         'Armed Forces Africa',
>         'Armed Forces Americas',
>         'Armed Forces Canada',
>         'Armed Forces Europe',
>         'Armed Forces Middle East',
>         'Armed Forces Pacific',
>         'Hawaii',
>         'Alaska'
>     ];
>
>     public function afterToOptionArray($subject, $options)
>     {
>         $result = array_filter($options, function ($option) {
>             if (isset($option['label']))
>                 return !in_array($option['label'], $this->disallowed);
>             return true;
>         });
>
>         return $result;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> To get the Plugin working, add this to your module's frontend
>   `di.xml`:
>
> ```
> <type name="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection">
>     <plugin name="MyCompany_MyModule_Limit_State_Filter_Plugin" type="MyCompany\MyModule\Plugin\StateFilter"/>
> </type>
> ```
>
> [More information about creating Plugins in Magento 2 here][1].
>
> [1]:
>   http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html